# Custom form designer, move/resize controls using WinAPI

Tags: c#, winapi, form-designer

I have to fix some problems and enchance form designer written long ago for a database project. 
In Design Panel class code I encountered these lines

```
private void DesignPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        (sender as Control).Capture = false;
        switch (FMousePosition)
        {
        case MousePosition.mpNone: 
            SendMessage((sender as Control).Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF009, 0);
            break;// Move
        case MousePosition.mpRightBottom: 
            SendMessage((sender as Control).Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF008, 0);
            break;//RB
        case MousePosition.mpLeftBottom: 
            SendMessage((sender as Control).Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF007, 0); 
            // ... here are similar cases ...
        case MousePosition.mpLeft:
            SendMessage((sender as Control).Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF001, 0);
            break;//L  
        }
    }
}
```

FMousePosition indicates whether mouse was over any edge of selected control.

What confusing me is these windows messages: it seems there is no documentation on  WM_SYSCOMMAND with parameters 0xF001-0xF009 (maybe it starts some kind of 'drag/resize sequence'). Any ideas?

If my suggestion is right, then how can I cancel these sequences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are [undocumented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360(VS.85).aspx) parameters.  After searching I managed to find this list.

- **0xF000** (`SC_SIZE`, Center cursor on the form)
- **0xF001** (`SC_SZLEFT`, Resize from left)
- **0xF002** (`SC_SZRIGHT`, Resize from right)
- **0xF003** (`SC_SZTOP`, Resize from top)
- **0xF004** (`SC_SZTOPLEFT`, Lock the bottom right corner of the form, the top left corner move for resize)
- **0xF005** (`SC_SZTOPRIGHT`, Same from bottom left corner)
- **0xF006** (`SC_SZBOTTOM`, Lock top right and left border, resize bottom)
- **0xF007** (`SC_SZBOTTOMLEFT`, Lock top and right border, resize other border)
- **0xF008** (`SC_SZBOTTOMRIGHT`, Lock left and top border and resize other)
- **0xF009** (`SC_SIZE|0x9`, Drag from anywhere)
- **0xF00F** (`SC_SEPARATOR`)
- **0xF010** (`SC_MOVE`, Put cursor centered at the upper order)
- **0xF012** (`SC_DRAGMOVE`, move by dragging)
- **0xF020** (`SC_MINIMIZE`, Auto-Minimize Form)
- **0xF030** (`SC_MAXIMIZE`, Auto-Maximize Form)
- **0xF040** (`SC_NEXTWINDOW`, Stop! You don't want that, it will lock all mouse click and make you reboot)
- **0xF148** (`SC_SCREENSAVE|0x8`, Activate ScreenSaver)
- **0xF13E** (`SC_TASKLIST|0xE`, Activate StartButton)

Reference: http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_1054.asp#Comments

Answer (score 1):

Based on my *Win32 Programming* (Rector and Newcomer) p902-903 explains *`WM_SYSCOMMAND` is sent when the user selects an item from the system menu* (rather than sending the normal `WM_COMMAND`).

The [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360(VS.85).aspx) says SC_SIZE = 0xF000 and it and *Win32 Programming* also say *Windows uses the four low-order bits of the predefined system menu IDs internally* but doesn't go on to clarify their use. Thanks stukelly for clarifying them.